# hasClass and dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understant if it is my use of `hasClass` or an issue with my `var sectionClass` but my script won't work. (My `console.log` return my class name very well).

```
$('#menu button').each(function(){
    var sectionClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log (sectionClass);
        $('section').hasClass(sectionClass).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: And what exactly do you want approach?

Comment: What's the value of `sectionClass`? Does it start with a dot? If yes, there's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write

```
$('#menu button').each(function(){
    var sectionClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log (sectionClass);
        $('section.' + sectionClass).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: No, hasClass returns a bool instead of a jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian, it solve the problem (and I learnt something) yay.